# React.js: Non-CSS animations

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, reactjs

[React documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/) doesn’t have anything about handling animations that are not CSS transitions, such as animation of scroll position and SVG attributes.

As for CSS transitions, there is [an add-on](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html).

Here is [a simple SVG example example](http://jsfiddle.net/NV/szrbs/):

[image: Animated SVG circle]

```
/**
 * @jsx React.DOM
 */


function animate(duration, onStep) {
    var start = Date.now();
    var timer = {id: 0};
    (function loop() {
        timer.id = requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            var diff = Date.now() - start;
            var fraction = diff / duration;
            onStep(fraction);
            if (diff < duration) {
                loop();
            }
        });
    })();
    return timer;
}

function lerp(low, high, fraction) {
    return low + (high - low) * fraction;
}


var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {x: 0}
    },

    move: function(i) {
        this.setState({x: this.state.x + i * 100});
    },

    render: function() {
        return <div className="ShowerItem">
            <p>
                <button onClick={this.move.bind(this, -1)}>Left</button>
                <button onClick={this.move.bind(this, 1)}>Right</button>
            </p>
            <svg><Dot x={this.state.x}/></svg>
        </div>;
    }
});



var Dot = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            x: 0,
            final: 0
        };
    },

    timer: null,

    render: function() {
        var from = this.state.x;
        var to = this.props.x;
        if (to !== this.state.final) {
            this.state.final = to;
            if (this.timer) {
                cancelAnimationFrame(this.timer.id);
            }

            this.timer = animate(500, function(fraction) {
                var x = lerp(from, to, fraction);
                if (fraction >= 1) {
                    this.setState({
                        value: to
                    });
                    this.timer = null;
                } else {
                    this.setState({x: x});
                }
            }.bind(this))
        }

        return <circle r="10" cy="10" cx={this.state.x + 10}/>
    }
});


React.renderComponent(
    <App/>,
    document.body
);
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing animations?
It the code architecture right?

[CSS Transitions add-on](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) doesn't help here since I don't use CSS.

Comment: This question is not about jQuery, and CSS wouldn’t do anything for the provided SVG example.

Comment: How does it look in the Chrome Timeline tab on your computer? For mine, a typical frame is: `0.503 ms Scripting, 0.070 ms Rendering, 0.821 ms Painting, 0.782 ms Other, 14.007 ms Idle` and the animation is smooth.

Comment: The animation is also quite smooth for me. You may also be interested in [this demo](https://github.com/petehunt/react-touch) (it's the one Pete Hunt shows off in the [JSConf.Asia talk "Rethinking Best Practices"](http://youtu.be/DgVS-zXgMTk?t=29m30s) at 29:30) that does animations via JavaScript.

Comment: Brandon Tilley, I’m looking at the demo and couldn’t find the code responsible for the animation. I don’t see any requestAnimationFrame calls outside of React.js itself. Could you point me out?

Comment: The demo code is at https://github.com/petehunt/react-touch, but all the good stuff is in https://github.com/petehunt/react-touch-lib. Another one you might want to look at is https://github.com/petehunt/react-raf-batching.

Comment: react-touch-lib uses ZyngaScroller, which is responsible for transformation changes. I don’t understand what does http://github.com/petehunt/react-raf-batching do. README.md doesn’t explain it.

Comment: You can check out https://github.com/aino/ainojs-animation that provides a simple animation interface with a `frame` callback that can be used to set states. There is a simple React example in the README.

Answer (score 2):

I successfully used this [project](https://github.com/pleasetrythisathome/react.animate) in my react-hammer integration [project](https://github.com/lapanoid/reactjs-hammerjs) there are some examples with hammer events and react animation.

Here code of animated "BlinkingThing":

```
var BlinkingThing = React.createClass({
    mixins: [React.Animate],
    blink: function () {
        var that = this;
        var animateAfter = function () {
            that.animate({
                color: 'green'
            }, that.props.blinkBack);
        };
        this.animate({
            color: 'yellow'
        }, this.props.blinkTo, animateAfter);
    },
    componentDidReceiveProps: function () {
        this.setState({color: this.props.color})
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.setState({color: this.props.color})
    },
    receiveHammerEvent: function (ev) {
        if (ev) {
            var value = ev.type;

            switch (value) {
                case 'tap':
                    this.blink();
                    break;
            }
        }
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {};
    },
    render: function () {
        var style = {
            display: 'inline-block',
            backgroundColor: this.state.color
        };

        return (<div style={style}>{this.props.children}</div>);
    }
});
```

You need some parent component which will propagate side effects(touch events, for example) to trigger changes of state in BlinkingThing component (animation rely on state changing when you call this.animate func), I made a HitArea component to do that. It calls receiveHammerEvent func from its children passing hammer event when it occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Been having the same exact problems myself, until recently I've found out about Rekapi.
This library provides state-based animations tools. Check out the tutorial https://github.com/jeremyckahn/rekapi/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md

The trick is, the context doesn't have to be a canvas or a DOM element, it can be a plain object, i.e. a component instance or a mixin, so this opens the possibility either to perform some logic in your actor's render method and then setState on your component(context), or simply write a "one trick actor" that always forwards its state to the component each frame.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [react.animate](https://github.com/pleasetrythisathome/react.animate) is an actively maintained and often used React animation libraries.

(it was already mentioned above, but would be easy to miss in all the links)

Note: it comes with/requires underscore.js.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I came up so far: http://jsfiddle.net/NV/NtP7n/.

I rewrote `Dot` to leverage React’s draw loop:

```
var Dot = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            start: 0,
            x: 0,
            final: 0,
            startTime: 0
        };
    },

    render: function() {
        var state = this.state;
        var props = this.props;
        var amount = 0;

        if (state.final !== props.x) {
            state.final = props.x;
            state.start = state.x;
            state.startTime = Date.now();
        } else {
            amount = (Date.now() - state.startTime) / this.props.duration;
        }

        if (amount <= 1) {
            var x = state.start + amount * (props.x - state.start);
            setTimeout(function() {
                this.setState({x: x});
            }.bind(this), 1);
        } else {
            state.final = state.x = x = props.x;
        }

        return <circle r="10" cy="10" cx={x + 10}/>
    }
});
```

I have to call:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    this.setState({current: x});
}.bind(this), 1);
```

just to force update on the next tick. I have to use setTimeout because setState isn’t allowed in `render` method. I wonder if I can queue an update on the next tick without using setTimeout.

Comment: You can probably hook into componentDidUpdate to queue the next state change. I accidentally triggered en infinite css transition loop by doing that :)