# React animate elements in component

Tags: animation, reactjs, state, element

I want to animate some elements inside a component without using jQuery or another similar library. I've got the following code running:

```
export default React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            women: {
                total: this.props.women.upvotes + this.props.women.downvotes,
                up_height: {
                    'height': 0
                },
                down_height: {
                    'height': 0
                }
            }
        };
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.setState({
            women: {
                up_height: {
                    'height': (this.props.women.upvotes / this.state.women.total) * 100 + '%'
                },
                down_height: {
                    'height': (this.props.women.downvotes / this.state.women.total) * 100 + '%'
                }
            }
        })
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <li className="block-element">
                <div className="upvotes">
                    <span className="women" style={this.state.women.up_height}>{this.props.women.upvotes}</span>
                    <span className="men">{this.props.men.upvotes}</span>
                </div>
            </li>
        )
    }
})
```

So on `getInitialState` the style height is set to 0. When de `componentDidMount` its set to the height it supposed to be. I did add a `transition` to the elements trough CSS, but nothing seem to happen.

I've tried adding a `setTimeout` around the `setState` in `componentDidMount`, but this broke the `setState`. Any heads up? How to make this work?

Comment: Using setTimeout should get you on the right track. Make sure to bind your callback argument to setTimeout to the correct context!

Comment: Damn such stupid. Forgot the .bind(this).. Thanks for pointing out ;)

Comment: Why not use CSS animations?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is using `requestAnimationFrame`, as used in [this (duplicate?) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906603/react-js-non-css-animations).

If you do not mind using a library implementing this functionality specifically for React, [react.animate](https://github.com/pleasetrythisathome/react.animate) (not to confuse with [react-animate](https://github.com/elierotenberg/react-animate)) does the thing. The current version (date: 9.4.16) on npm seems not to support CommonJS, but the version on github is more up to date. As an example:

```
npm install react react-dom http://github.com/pleasetrythisathome/react.animate/tarball/master
```

test.js :

```
React = require('react')
ReactDOM = require('react-dom')
require('@pleasetrythisathome/react.animate')

SomeComponent = React.createClass({
  mixins: [React.Animate],
  getInitialState: function () {return {bananas: 0}},
  componentDidMount: function () {
    this.animate({bananas: 100}, 1000, () => {console.log('Finish')})
  },
  render: function () {return React.DOM.span({}, this.state.bananas)},
})

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(SomeComponent), document.getElementById('apple'))
```

then e.g. with browserify

```
browserify test.js > apple.js
```

test.html :

```
<div id="apple"></div>
<script src="apple.js"></script>
```

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jo5tp5mt/